# Cannot get or delete all entities using Google Datatstore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, webapp2

I'm building a Webapp2 application using datastore in the development server. Sometimes, I cannot get all entities after I saved many entities. In other words, I cannot get all entities precisely.

Code snippet:

```
def saveItems(self, items):
    # Get all existed items
    existed_items = model.Items.all()
    existed_ids = [item.myid for item in existed_items]

    # Save new items
    save_count = 0
    skip_count = 0
    for groups in [items[i:i+10] for i in range(0, len(items), 10)]:
        save_items = []
        for item in groups:
            # Check this item whether exist or not
            if item.id not in existed_ids:
                save_item = model.Item(myid=item.id)
                save_items.append(save_item)
            else:
                skip_count += 1
        db.put(save_items)

    # Total
    save_count += len(save_items)

    print "Save-Items, all: %s, save: %s, skip: %s" %\
            (len(items), save_count, skip_count))
```

If I have 100 new entities, I executed this method at the first time and it showed correctly:

```
Save-Items, all: 100, save: 100, skip: 0
```

But, I executed this method right away with same data and it showed:

```
Save-Items, all: 100, save: 3, skip: 97
```

It should show `save:0 skip: 100`. I checked the datastore viewer, and it showed that there were 103 entities. In the second execution, I found out in line 3 `model.Items.all()` only retrieved 97 entities. Therefore, I assume that there were some entities had not been committed in the second execution.

How you guys resolve this problem? What is your solution to the situation? Is there a better solution to check whether a entity exist or not? Or, how can I make sure that the `put()` is really completed?

Please share your opinion with me. Thank you so much!

Comment: Eventual consistency: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency

Comment: By the way, I'm using a Raspberry Pi as a web server.